# Função getJSON não mostra informação na tela

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, getjson

Boa Noite Gente, preciso muito de uma ajuda.

Estou montando dinamicamente uma tabela que lista uma quantidade X de atendimentos. Para isso estou utilizando AJAX para consultar no banco de dados e exibir na página. Até ai tudo bem, sem nenhum problema.

Porém um dos itens que preciso exibir nessa listagem são os "tipos de atendimentos" que foram realizados em cada atendimento específico.

Exemplo: "No atendimento ID 5223 em nome do João da Silva, foram realizados atendimentos voltados para: Cartão de Crédito, Cheque Especial e CDC."

Visto isso, montei um array que contem os ID dos tipos de atendimentos e através desses IDs em tese eu volto a consultar o banco de dados para pegar o nome desses atendimentos e me listar também na tela para o usuário.

Importante ressaltar que um atendimento do cliente pode ter 01 ou mais tipos de atendimentos.

De qualquer forma, o X da questão é que estou utilizando a função getJSON para buscar essas informações dos tipos de atendimentos.

No entanto ela não me mostra nada na tela.

Se eu coloco o resultado num alert(), eu consigo verificar que está buscando o resultado normalmente. No entanto na tela do usuário não aparece.

Dei uma estudada por cima, a respeito das requisições AJAX sem assincronas, e tentei até implementar alterações no código. E nenhum deu certo, de forma que fiquei realmente sem visão algum de resolver isso.

Se puderem me auxiliar a achar um caminho.

Estou copiando apenas a parte que interessa do código. Antes dessa parte tem apenas um SUCCESS do AJAX.

Segue o código:

```
var retorno = JSON.parse(data);

var linha = "";

for (var i = 0; i < retorno.length; i++) {

  var tipos = retorno[i].tipo.split(',');

  linha += "<tr>";
  linha += "<td class='text-center'><h6 class='text-default font-weight-semibold letter-icon-title'>" + retorno[i].codigo + "</h6></td>";
  linha += "<td class='text-center'><h6 class='mb-0'>" + retorno[i].senha + "</h6><div class='font-size-sm text-muted line-height-1'>senha</div></td>";
  linha += "<td>";
  linha += "<a href='#' class='carregaDados text-default font-weight-semibold' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modal_visualiza_atendimento' data-id='" + retorno[i].codigo + "'>" + retorno[i].cliente + "</a>";

  for (var a = 0; a < tipos.length; a++) {
    $.getJSON("funcoes/carregaTipoAtendimento.php?tipo=" + tipos[a]).done(function(t) {
      linha += "<span class='badge badge-flat border-" + cor + " text-" + cor + "'>" + tipo + "</span>";
    });
  }

  linha += "</td>";
  linha += "<td class='text-center'><i class='icon-calendar3 position-left'></i> " + retorno[i].data + "</td>";

  if (retorno[i].prazo == "sim") {
    linha += "<td class='text-center'><span class='badge bg-success'>" + retorno[i].duracao + "</span></td>";
  } else {
    linha += "<td class='text-center'><span class='badge bg-danger'>" + retorno[i].duracao + "</span></td>";
  }

  linha += "<td class='text-center'><img src='assets/images/" + codigo_convenio + "/" + retorno[i].usuario + ".jpg' class='rounded-circle' width='40' height='40'></td>";
  linha += "</tr>";

}
```

Comment: Lembrou-se de adicionar o header na resposta?

Comment: Por que não trazer esses dados junto com cada item `retorno[i]`? Mais simples e eficiente. O problema desse seu código atual é que não adianta mais querer alterar a variável `linha` na resposta do getJSON, já é tarde demais pra isso.